# Delimit File System Rights by " - " instead of comma " , "

Tags: powershell

I am in the process of creating a PowerShell script to output the file system rights enabled on a group of directories from a windows server to a CSV. The problem I am having is that the file system rights are delimited by comma " , " which means that when I open the CSV these file system rights appear separate columns. I would like them to appear all within one column. So something like this " ReadData-ExecuteFile-Synchronize " instead of " ReadData {new column} ExecuteFile {new column} Synchronize ". Here's an extract of the code that I use to write to the CSV.

```
$file_stream_output.WriteLine(('{0}, {1}, {2}' -f $directory.FullName, $access_right.IdentityReference, $access_right.FileSystemRights))
```

Comment: `($access_right.FileSystemRights) -replace ",","-"`?

Comment: normally, the `Export-CSV` cmdlet adds double quotes around the values of each column. so i don't see how you managed to have the problem ... [*grin*]

Comment: I am engineering this for PS 2.0 and consequently can't use export-csv

Comment: Thanks @JeffZeitlin but now everything is appearring on one line (i.e. $directory.FullName, $access_right.IdentityReference, $access_right.FileSystemRights). I just want the comma to be replaced from FileSystemRights.

Comment: Please show examples of your original output, the desired output, and the output after you tested my suggestion.

Comment: Wait I got it :-) Thanks @JeffZeitlin
$file_stream_output.WriteLine(('{0}, {1}, {2}' -f $directory.FullName, $access_right.IdentityReference, ($access_right.FileSystemRights -replace ",","-")))

Comment: PS v2 is ancient and obsolete.. that computer needs some updates!

Comment: @JamesC - often one has to engineer for legacy servers ;-)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] as well as examples of desired and actual output. Also, what makes you believe `Export-Csv` would not work in PowerShell v2?